# Rotate a UIlabel to make it vertical

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

I have a UILabel. I need to rotate it programmatically.

I have my horizontal UILabel, for example with frame: `x:0, y:0, w: 200, h:80`.

Now I would like to rotate the label to make it vertical:
I try this code:

```
 [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 / 2)];
```

I can see the contained text rotated. But I would like to rotate the whole frame: With my code, the UILabel continues to have the same frame.

Comment: `Warning: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.` From the doc of the `transform` property of `UIView`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this working code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 80)];
//set background color to see if the frame is rotated
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setText:@"Text Here"];
label.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 90 * M_PI ) / 180 );
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer set the label position and size visually in you xib or storyboard do the following:

1. Set the labels position and size in the interface builder like you want them to stay after the rotation.
2. Rotate the label and set the frame again:

   ```
   -(void)rotateLabel:(UILabel*) label
   {
       CGRect orig = label.frame;
       label.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 3/2);//270º
       label.frame = orig;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your Label is a square(w:100,h:100).So your label has transformed, but you can't see the change，because the width is equal to the height.

Comment: ok sorry...I reported wrong H and W: We can suppose that the UILabel is 200x80